# In LotusScript - trying to update the current document from a sub routine in the querysave event but the data doesn't save as expected

Tags: lotusscript

in the postopen statement I have these initialized

```
Sub Postopen(Source As Notesuidocument) 
Print "Opening Document"
DocWasSaved = False
Dim WorkflowObject As String
Set w = New NotesUIWorkspace
Set UIDoc = w.CurrentDocument
Set doc = source
Set note = source.Document
```

In my Querysave event I am calling subroutines - this is one of them.
SetNextApprover

Here is the code for the SetNextApprover:

```
Sub SetNextApprover
On Error Goto ProcessError
Print "SettingNextApprover"
Dim holdingStatus As String
holdingStatus = note.DocStatus(0)
Dim email As String
Dim email2 As String
Dim nam As NotesName
Dim newCommon As String
Dim newCommon2 As String
Dim SaveOptions As Variant
Dim holdingStep As String
Dim holdOldStatus As String
Dim plannerName As String
Dim plannerName2 As String  
Dim curName As NotesName    
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
Set curName = s.CreateName(s.UserName)
CurrentUser = curName.Common
Dim holdFunction As String

Select Case holdingStatus
Case "Awaiting Initial Review"          
Dim MaximumApprovers As String
MaximumApprovers = note.MaximumApprovers(0)
Dim HoldSubmitBy As String
HoldSubmitBy = note.submitBy(0)

Select Case HoldSubmitBy
Case "CSR"
If note.Function1(0) <> "" Then
If note.App1Name(0) <> "" Then
If note.App1Name(0) = CurrentUser Then      
If note.Status1(0) <> "" Then                       If note.App2Name(0) <> "" Then
    nextApprover = note.App2NameNote(0)
    plannerName = note.App2NameNote(0)
    note.nextApproverCommon = plannerName
        email = lookupEmailAddress(plannerName)                     note.NextApprover = email       
End If
End If
End Select
Exit Sub
ProcessError:Msgbox "Error(" & Cstr(Err) & ") -> " & 
Error$(Err), 16, "SetNextApprover"  
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The issue I have is that the value for the line >>note.NextApprover = email<< does not retain the value in the document for the NextApprover field with the email value.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.  I have done these type of updates before and they have worked.
I am on a time crunch with this and any comments are very much appreciated.

Thank you.
Jean

Comment: Are you sure that the email variable contains the correct value? Are there any Conversion formulas defined on the field, if any, defined in the form? Did you try to run this in the Lotusscript Debugger?

Comment: I ran the code through the debugger and the values are in the note.nextApproverCommon field, but as soon as I have left that routine the value is no longer captured in the form.

Answer (score 2):

The QuerySave event occurs before the save.

You are updating note.nextApproverCommon, but the field nextApproverCommon is unchanged in the NotesUIDocument (source). Then the save happens after your QuerySave sub returns, and the old value in the NotesUIDocument's nextApproverCommon field overwrites the value you wrote in note.nextApproverCommon.

Answer (score 0):

Check Richards answere first.

So, you should manipulate the value in the NotesUIDocument or you should manipulate the value after the save.